# R: Import of xls data from website generated by a button-triggered event

Tags: r

I want to import xls data from this website (https://ec.europa.eu/food/plant/pesticides/eu-pesticides-database/public/?event=activesubstance.selection&language=EN) into R as a df. The website has an "Export to Excel" button at the top, which triggers the generation of the complete xls-file (which I need) and provides a download event from the server (means no direct download link for the xls-file).

I am totally clueless on all js-stuff - is there any way to import the data automatically into R? Downloading the xls by hand and importing it into R works easily, but since the data is updated frequently some automatism to innitiate the download and import the newest version would be nice.
Apologies that I could not provide any syntax example, but I have totally no idea how to approach this issue...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that kind of web scraping, but it seems like the 'Export to Excel' button simply converts the table to excel format and downloads it.
The table itself is available as a JSON file at https://ec.europa.eu/food/plant/pesticides/eu-pesticides-database/public/?event=activesubstance.GetJson.

The following code downloads that table and converts it to a nice `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/food/plant/pesticides/eu-pesticides-database/public/?event=activesubstance.GetJson"

json <- read_json(url)

data <- map(json$DATA, setNames, json$COLUMNS)

df <- tibble(data = data) %>% 
  unnest_wider(data)

df
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 1,429 x 6
   SUBSTANCES_ID NOM                 ACT_SUB_STATUS LEG_ACT                         ACT_SUB_INCUSION_F  ACT_SUB_INCUSION_T
           <int> <chr>               <chr>          <chr>                           <chr>               <chr>             
 1           817 (4Z-9Z)-7,9-Dodeca… Out            2004/129/EC                     NA                  NA                
 2           824 (E)-10-Dodecen-1-y… Out            2004/129/EC                     NA                  NA                
 3           825 (E)-11-Tetradecen-… In             Reg. (EU) No 540/2011Reg. (EU)… September, 01 2009… August, 31 2021 0…
 4           826 (E)-2-Methyl-6-met… Out            2007/442                        NA                  NA                
 5           827 (E)-2-Methyl-6-met… Out            Reg 647/2007                    NA                  NA                
 6           828 (E)-5-Decen-1-ol    In             Reg. (EU) No 540/2011Reg. (EU)… September, 01 2009… August, 31 2021 0…
 7           829 (E)-5-Decen-1-yl a… In             Reg. (EU) No 540/2011Reg. (EU)… September, 01 2009… August, 31 2021 0…
 8           830 (E)-8-Dodecen-1-yl… In             Reg. (EU) No 540/2011Reg. (EU)… September, 01 2009… August, 31 2021 0…
 9          1277 (E)-9-Dodecen-1-yl… Out            2007/442                        NA                  NA                
10           818 (E,E)-7,9-Dodecadi… In             Reg. (EU) No 540/2011Reg. (EU)… September, 01 2009… August, 31 2021 0…
# … with 1,419 more rows
```

### Edit

I misread the JavaScript code in which `GetJson` was replaced by `exportList`. If you change it to this, it downloads a large xls file and reads it in R.

```
url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/food/plant/pesticides/eu-pesticides-database/public/?event=activesubstance.exportList"

httr::GET(url, httr::write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
df <- readxl::read_excel(tf, skip = 2)
```

Comment: First thanks for the reply. The xls table generated is MUCH larger - this is only the data on the page itself to select some entries. But the xls provided for download has 30+ columns with information not displayed on the page.

Comment: Apologies – see the edit for the full xls file download and reading.

Comment: NP - but it still does not work ("Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) :   Failed to connect to ec.europa.eu port 443: Connection refused"). Am I missing a package? (httr, curl are installed).

Comment: That is strange, it does work with me. Could you try adding the request headers you see if you do "inspect element", go to "network", filter on "XHR" and refresh the page? Maybe it looks for a cookie or something like that, or maybe your IP did too many requests and got blocked? Adding headers can be done with `httr::add_headers()`.

Comment: I checked it on my laptop with mobile hotspot IP - ran perfectly. Need to talk to IT-dep., if they blocked some stuff at works desktop. THANKS ALOT!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question